# Will VS2012 work with TFS2010?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I'm considering using VS2012 RC to put together coded UI tests (since VS2010 SP2 FP2 does not fully support IE9).

Currently, my test projects are contained within a solution which is connected to our TFS team project. I also set up a build definition to build the project when new code is checked in (the builds are performed on our build machine).

I suppose that if I upgrade my solution to VS2012, then to be able to build the solution on the build machine I will need VS2012 RC installed there too, right? But then is it possible to specify in my build definition for my project to be built by VS2012 instead of VS2010?

Is it possible for me to upgrade my project with VS2012 while still using TFS2010? I should note my solution will be the only one upgraded to VS2012. All the other solutions in the company still need to be built by VS2010. A company-wide upgrade to VS2012 won't be in place for at least a few months, I imagine.

Or do I need a separate build machine or anything?

Any thoughts, ideas or solutions appreciated!

UPDATE: So I gave it a try, and everything worked okay. My only problem is that the Coded UI tests I have didn't work after being re-built on on my build machine, but I suppose that's probably something I'd need to ask about elsewhere. To clarify, the solution built successfully, but the tests still failed.

Comment: At our company three developers are using Visual Studio 2012 and 4 are using VS10. We have had no problems with; TFS2010, or our source/controller and agent servers. So all looks good to me. (Fingers crossed!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012's project changes allow most types to still be opened by Visual Studio 2010 with SP1, so it depends on what kind of projects are in your solution - see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx) for the full compatibility list:

> If you created your assets in Visual Studio 2010 with Service Pack 1
>   (SP1), many of them will load and run in Visual Studio 2012 without
>   any further action on your part. Many assets will also open again in
>   Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 without any issues, even after you open
>   those assets in Visual Studio 2012.

See also ["Round-tripping with Visual Studio 11"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx) on the VS blog which has more detail.

Note though that if your build process uses custom build activities then just installing Visual Studio 2012 [breaks the build definition on your local machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/07/17/tfs-2012-cleaning-up-workflow-xaml-files-aka-removing-versioned-namespaces.aspx), and also that MVC1 or MVC2 projects just aren't supported by VS2012. Oh, and Visual Studio 2012 isn't a RC any more, it was RTM'd last week.

Answer (score 3):

(I presume you mean 2012 RTM rather than RC, now that the final release is available)

Theoretically (from what I've read) VS2012 and VS2010 use the same project/solution file format, so you should be able to switch between them without any compatibility issues (aside, presumably from obvious things like creating new file types that VS2010 doesn't understand)

TFS updates have historically been backwards compatible, so you can usually use different client and server versions (but usually you need a compatibility pack installed for old clients on new servers, a new client running against an old server has usualyl been fine). So I'd expect this to work well.

I'd say try it, but diff any files that appear in VCS2012's Pending Changes carefully before you check in to be sure that it hasn't changed anything that will cause problems. The worst that can happen then is that your development machine gets a "corrupt" version of the code and you'll need to revert to 2010.

(This is the approach I've been using with our 130-project C# solution, and so far (1 day) it's working fine, apart from the new UI making my eyes bleed as they try to find the information in all the indistinguishable monochrome clutter)